# Three virtio-blk devices crashing Windows 10 VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

If three `virtio-blk` devices are added VM is crashing in the middle of the Windows 10 boot. The attached `blockdev` has no influence. VM is working fine using two `virtio-blk`.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
...
-device virtio-blk,drive=c,bus=pci.3,addr=0x0,write-cache=on,bootindex=1 \
-device virtio-blk,drive=d,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0,write-cache=on \
-device virtio-blk,drive=e,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0,write-cache=on \
...
```

`qemu-system-x86_64` exits without printing any information. How to debug in this situation? Maybe there are known reasons why this is happening.

Context: Kubernetes, privileged Debian container, Qemu 5.2.0

Comment: afaik the device address `addr=` should be different for each device. Can you test by incrementing the addr value and make sure no other devices use the same address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried everything that came to my mind and gave up. This is the workaround that I will be using:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
...
-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=c,bus=pci.1,write-cache=on,bootindex=0 \
-device ide-hd,drive=d \
-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=e \
...
```

Had to switch one of the drives to `ide-hd`.